# How to replace a single character from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I replace a single character in a string in python?

For example: If I have a string abcccc and I want to replace the c at the third position, if I use .replace() it will replace every single c in the string.

Comment: replace has a occurance parameter with that you can control how many times it will replace. If you google it you will find it

Answer (score 3):

To set a single character in a string, try something like:

#### Code:

```
def set_at_string_position(a_string, a_char, position):
    if position < 0 or len(a_string) <= position:
        return a_string
    return a_string[:position] + a_char + a_string[position+1:]
```

#### Test Code:

```
print(set_at_string_position('123456789', 'a', -1))
print(set_at_string_position('123456789', 'a', 0))
print(set_at_string_position('123456789', 'a', 3))
print(set_at_string_position('123456789', 'a', 8))
print(set_at_string_position('123456789', 'a', 9))
```

#### Result:

```
123456789
a23456789
123a56789
12345678a
123456789
```